# Timezone issue Data Loader

Tags: apex, trigger, data-loader, datetime, timezone

I have to upload a csv file in which a DateTime field has values across the global timezone, however I want to load this data in my org keeping the timezone consistent with my org.

e.g. In CSV values might be -
for Country A - GMT+1
For Country B - GMT -1

For Country C- - GMT + 3

Data in My salesforce org should be GMT.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you load the data, it must all be in the same time zone. Are you saying your data has dateTime values that will need to be converted before you upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Important part is that how datetime format is specified in each country based csv file.

**Scenario 1**

Org time zone is GMT and dataloader timezone is GMT and all the datetime of csv files are in this format

- 2017-04-10
- 2017-04-10 00:00:00
- 2017-04-10T00:00:00Z
- 2017-04-10T00:00:00.000Z

Then you are safe to upload the data.

**Scenario 2**

Org time zone is GMT and dataloader timezone is GMT

Let's say, check the country data whose timezone is GMT+1 hour is specified as

`2017-04-10T01:00:00Z` or 
`2017-04-10T01:00:00.000Z`.

Then importing file from dataloader will not be an issue.

Salesforce stores the datetime in GMT format and will be shown to the user based on user's timezone.

**Scenario 3**

If the csv contains the format without any timezone then following data will take GMT timezone:

`2017-04-10` or
`2017-04-10 00:00:00`

So, it will be advisable to match csv datetime zone with dataloader timezone.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionally you need to change the date time zone in three below things :

1. change the Data Loader time Zone to GMT.
2. Change your System(Computer) time Zone to GMT.
3. Lastly change the Time Zone of the user which you are using to load the data.

By implementing this change you can achieve this.

I have done the same and it is working fine.

Comment: you r right, but some time when we are loading the data for a long time in on session, it might happen that the data loader takes the system time zone, so be on safer side make all three in sync.

Answer (score 0):

For this close your Data Loader. Then set the system time (the computer from where you are running the data loader) zone to the time zone of your Salesforce.com org 
I think the Z stands for Zero TO displacement from GMT.See that how many hours you are behind of GMT so it should work if you replace the Z with -08:00 for example (or whatever the time difference really is).
After this start your data loader and load the data.